# Linear Demand Equation - Max Revenue

Tags: linear-algebra

I was having a bit of trouble with a math question regarding a "linear demand equation".

The problem asks: "A company can sell $30$ products at a price of \$$20$ per product. For every dollar in price increase they sell 2 fewer products per day. Find a linear equation for the amount expected to sell, $A$, as a function of price, $p$."

The equation turned out (I hope) to be: $$A = (-2/1)p + 30$$

However, it then asks with the equation $$R = pA$$ at what price will revenue ($R$) be highest, what is the highest price, and how many widgets are sold at highest. Basically, I need to find the vertex, but this is where I'm stuck. I'm not really sure how to proceed from here, as I always have trouble finding the vertex without a graph. What I tried was inputting a random price like so: $$R = 2(-2/1(2)+30)$$ which gave me $56$, but that doesn't fit. Could anyone point me in the right direction? I struggle really badly with these.

Thanks!

Comment: The amount $A$ sold at price $p\ge 20$ should be $(-2)(p-20)+30$.

Comment: Ohh, that makes sense. If I did that, then my equation for revenue would actually be R=22(-2(2)+30), so that would give me a completely different outcome... I'll try that real quick, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. You will find that the result looks a lot more reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amount $A$ sold at price $p\ge 20$ should be $(-2)(p-20)+30$.  For the problem says that for every dollar in price *increase* the amount sold decreases by $2$.

So $A=70-2p$, and therefore $R=70p-2p^2$.

The curve with equation $y=70x-2x^2$ is a downward-facing parabola. We can find the vertex by completing the square, or by noting it is halfway between the roots of $70x-2x^2=0$.

**Remark:** We end up with the fact that $70p-2p^2$ is maximized at $p=\frac{35}{2}$. This is *below* the price of $20$.

There are two possible conclusions. If the price/demand relationship holds *below* $p=20$, then we maximize revenue at $p=\frac{35}{2}$.

However, if the relationship does not hold below $20$, or for some reason going below $20$ is forbidden, then maximum revenue is at [price $20$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, factoring the result turned up P as 35, at which point both the revenue and the amount sold are 0. So whenever I plug in that amount to any of the equations I get 0. I think I'm missing something here, but I'm not really sure how to get the max revenue from that. I apologize for not understanding, I just can't seem to grasp this for some reason.

Comment: The answer I gave said complete  the square, or note that the vertex is halfways between the roots of $70x-2x^2=0$. The two roots are $0$ and $35$, giving halfway point $17.5$. This means the price should *decrease* (assuming the price effect works for decreases as well as increases).

Comment: Or else complete the square, $R=-2\left((p-35/2)^2-(35/2)^2 \right)$, from which again we get price that maximizes revenue is $35/2$.

Comment: Okay, I understand now, I'll give this a try. Thanks a ton for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your equation for $A$ is not quite correct. You have the slope correct, but since you are given $A = 30$ when $p = \$20$ you need to solve

$$30 = -2(20) + b$$

for $b$. This gives $b = 70$ so $$A = -2p + 70$$

You now have $$R = pA = p(-2p + 70) = -2p^2 + 70p$$ You can find the derivative of $R$ with respect to $p$, set it to $0$, and solve for $p$. This gives you the price that maximizes the revenue, which you can use in your equations for $R$ and $A$ to find the maximum revenue and number of widgets are sold at that maximum.